# What does it mean by Proving false

Tags: logic, proof-theory, paradoxes

With respect to the recent finding of a [bug](https://github.com/clarus/falso) in a Coq theorem prover in which `false` was proved, I'm asking this question.

As a hobbyist studying maths, I'm wondering what does it mean by "proving false" and what are the consequences of it ?

Comment: Coq runs on type theory.  Then "false" is a type representative of a false statement.  Thus Coq proved a false statement.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Can you explain what is the consequence of proving a "false statement" true then?

Comment: It seems this "bug" has been around for years. It is obviously not just a software bug, but a much deeper, theoretical problem. Without using Coq notation, how is this internal contradiction obtained? See Coq session output at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75604/why-should-i-trust-coq-when-assumption-free-proof-of-false-in-coq-exists

Comment: @Sibi You don't want math software that might accidentally prove false things.  If Coq can prove "false" then it might somehow prove $1+1=3$.  It could have a snowball effect if it proves false things in the middle of a bigger proof.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Thanks, In a bigger picture is this the same thing as principle of explosion ?

Comment: @Sibi That's right.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Thanks, if you can add this as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coq runs on type theory. Then "false" is a type representative of a false statement. Thus Coq proved a false statement.

You don't want math software that might accidentally prove false things. If Coq can prove "false" then it might somehow prove $1+1=3$. It could have a snowball effect if it proves false things in the middle of a bigger proof.